# ddply() error: Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id, id_as_factor) : Results do not have equal lengths

Tags: plyr

This error popped up in a script that I thought I had run successfully a year ago. I modified it from this script:  https://gist.github.com/noamross/bf8ebdcf42fd2e0851a8

Downloading and running the Noam Ross script I get the error here:
n_options<-ddply (andre, c("YEAR"), function (df)
return(table(df$CLASS)))
Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id, id_as_factor) :
Results do not have equal lengths

Everything loads as expected up to that point.

I am sure I ran it successfully a year ago. Perhaps a package update issue? I have R 4.1.2, plyr 1.8.6, reshape 0.8.8. Just updated all packages, still get the error.  I am not really understanding what the ddply() is trying to do since I can't look at successful output from the original Noam Ross script or from one of my modified scripts.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `ddply` could not find levels in a dataframe. Adding `stringsAsFactors = T` to the read CSV statement solved the problem. Though I still don't know why the original script used to work without the read CSV modification, but no longer does.